# difference between url pattern urls in django

Tags: django, url-pattern

What is the difference between

```
1. url(r'^$', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
```

and

```
2. url(r'^.*', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
```

in view.py:

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

Output of 1 is it will redirect only to index.html when clicked on the other it says

```
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

output of 2nd is: it shows UI pages but backgroup django application apis doesnt execute.